# How to update client new secret in Azure key vault

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault, secret-key

My client secret is expired so I need to update the secret, how can I update secret in Azure key vault in Azure data factory using azure portal.

How to update new client secret in Azure key vault, and how to set expired dates

Comment: Could you confirm whether your requirement to create new client secret in Azure AD  app registration like [this](https://i.imgur.com/s5gxfQN.png) and update key vault secret value with this new secret value by creating new version?

Comment: @Chinnu, Can you provide what you have tried so far? any errors/blockers?

Comment: @Sridevi, create new client secret and update key vault

Comment: Will PowerShell script to create new client secret and update key vault works for you?

Comment: How can I use powershell script, could you please give some screenshots

Comment: I need only update the secret key

Comment: In my case, I ran this PowerShell script that create new client secret and updates key vault secret with new value like [this](https://i.imgur.com/qBwJXEx.png). Check if this works for you so that I can post it as answer

Comment: I'm new to powershell, how can take secret value and how can I update in Azure portal

Comment: Could you please share clear process for better understanding

Comment: @Chinnu You can check the below added answer with screenshots

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256885/discussion-between-sridevi-and-chinnu).

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I registered one Azure AD application and created **client secret** in it like this:

[image]

In my Azure key vault, I added one secret with above **value** like this:

[image]

To create **new** client secret in Azure AD app registration and **update** key vault secret value, you can run below PowerShell script in Azure Cloud Shell:

```
$resourceGroupName = "YourRGname"
$keyVaultName = "YourKVname"
$secretName = "YourKBsecretname"
$appName = "YourAzureADappName"

$existingSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $secretName -AsPlainText
Write-Output "Existing secret value: $existingSecret"

$customKeyIdentifier = "newSecret"
$customKeyIdentifierBase64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($customKeyIdentifier))

$clientSecret = New-AzADAppCredential -DisplayName $appName -CustomKeyIdentifier $customKeyIdentifierBase64 -EndDate (Get-Date).AddYears(1) 
$secretValue = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $clientSecret.SecretText -AsPlainText -Force

Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $secretName -SecretValue $secretValue
Write-Output "New client secret created and updated in Key Vault successfully."

$newSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $secretName -AsPlainText
Write-Output "New secret value: $newSecret"
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where new **client secret** is created in Azure AD app like this:

[image]

In Azure Key vault also, secret **updated** successfully with new client secret value by creating **new version** as below:

[image]